# Create unique index with SQLAlchemy on Postgres using MD5

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, unique-constraint, unique-index

I have a column that can contain a long text, that I want to create a unique index on.

I read on several places (for example [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94205/unique-constraint-on-large-varchars-postgresql)) that the way to do it is to create an index on the MD5 of the column.

I tried adding the following code:

```
__table_args__ = (
        sa.Index('unique_data_hash', 'MD5(data)', unique=True)
    )
```

but when I try to use it I get

> KeyError: 'MD5(data)'

How can I add such index using SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After another search I realised the answer is to use sa.func.md5, which worked like a charm!

Comment: Are you able to use any other hash function? MD5 has not the best track record with hash collisions. @aviad-nissel